# Joining Multiparts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, multipart

How do you combine two parts of a multipart polygon into one multipart.

Eg: Below: I would like to join the two highlighted multiparts of a polygon, yet keep the other multiparts (not highlighted) separate.

I have tried using the Edit--> Union tool, but to no avail.

Using ArcMap 10.2

[image: Merge?]

Comment: Have you tried EDIT>Merge instead if needed?

Comment: Tried it originally, but it didn't do anything. However it appears to work if you first use Union(edit) then Merge(edit). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, it appears that you have to first using the Union tool in the edit stage, then using the Merge tool in the edit stage. This will create one shape!